# Compare two schemas using SQL only in H2

Tags: sql, diff, h2

I have two schemas in H2 database: `PUBLIC` and `TEST`. I want to find out whether the tables in `PUBLIC` and `TEST` are the same (same columns with the same datatypes) and if not, which tables are different. So far I simply select the information neccessary in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and compare it myself using a shell script. But I was wondering whether I can use pure SQL to for example select only the tables that are different.

Comment: You could do use the [`SCRIPT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) command to create a SQL script for each schema (the command supports filtering by schema), then find / replace the schema name, and compare the SQL scripts using a GUI diff tool, but I'm not sure if you want a manual or automated way to compare, and whether you want a solution for H2 or one that also works with other databases?

Comment: @ThomasMueller H2 only is enough, but must be automated.